# numpy: column-wise dot product

Tags: python, numpy, dot-product

Given a 2D `numpy` array, I need to compute the dot product of every column with itself, and store the result in a 1D array. The following works:

```
In [45]: A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

In [46]: np.array([np.dot(A[:,i], A[:,i]) for i in xrange(A.shape[1])])
Out[46]: array([26, 40, 58, 80])
```

Is there a simple way to avoid the Python loop? The above is hardly the end of the world, but if there's a `numpy` primitive for this, I'd like to use it.

**edit** In practice the matrix has many rows and relatively few columns. I am therefore not overly keen on creating temporary arrays larger than `O(A.shape[1])`. I also can't modify `A` in place.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
>>> (A*A).sum(axis=0)
array([26, 40, 58, 80])
```

---

EDIT:  Hmm, okay, you don't want intermediate large objects.  Maybe:

```
>>> from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d
>>> A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
>>> inner1d(A.T, A.T)
array([26, 40, 58, 80])
```

which seems a little faster anyway.  This should do what you want behind the scenes, as A.T is a view (which doesn't make its own copy, IIUC), and inner1d *seems* to loop the way it needs to.

VERY BELATED UPDATE: Another alternative would be to use `np.einsum`:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
>>> np.einsum('ij,ij->j', A, A)
array([26, 40, 58, 80])
>>> timeit np.einsum('ij,ij->j', A, A)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.65 us per loop
>>> timeit inner1d(A.T, A.T)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.02 us per loop
>>> A = np.random.randint(0, 100, (2, 100000))
>>> timeit np.einsum('ij,ij->j', A, A)
1000 loops, best of 3: 363 us per loop
>>> timeit inner1d(A.T, A.T)
1000 loops, best of 3: 848 us per loop
>>> (np.einsum('ij,ij->j', A, A) == inner1d(A.T, A.T)).all()
True
```

Comment: `inner1d` appears to be just the ticket. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the square of all elements and sum up column-wise using

```
np.sum(np.square(A),0);
```

(I'm not entirely sure about the second parameter of the `sum` function, which identifies the axis along which to take the sum, and I have no numpy currently installed. Maybe you'll have to experiment :) ...)

**EDIT**

Looking at *DSM*'s post, it seems that you should use `axis=0`. Using the `square` function might be a little more performant than using `A*A`.

Answer (score 0):

From linear algebra, the dot product of row i with row j is the i,j th entry of AA^T. Similarly, the dot product of column i with column j is the i,jth entry of (A^T)A.

So if you want the dot product of each column vector of A with itself, you could use `ColDot = np.dot(np.transpose(A), A).diagonal()`. On the other hand, if you want the dot product of each row with itself, you could use `RowDot = np.dot(A, np.transpose(A)).diagonal()`.

Both lines return an array.