# Using Python numpy einsum to obtain dot product between 2 Matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, dot-product

Just came across this:

[Vectorized way of calculating row-wise dot product two matrices with Scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616742/vectorized-way-of-calculating-row-wise-dot-product-two-matrices-with-scipy)

This numpy.einsum is really awesome but its a little confusing to use. Suppose I have:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [3,4,5]])
b = np.array([[0,1,2], [1,1,7]])
```

How would i use the "ij" in einsum to get a "cross dot product" between a and b?

Using the example basically I would like to compute dot product of

[1,2,3] and [0,1,2]

[1,2,3] and [1,2,7]

[3,4,5] and [0,1,2]

[3,4,5] and [1,1,7]

and end up with [[8,26],[14,42]]

I know if I use

```
np.einsum("ij,ij->i",a,b)
```

I would just end up with [8, 42] which means I am missing the "cross" elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your result is still 2 dimensional, so you need two indices. What you need is a matrix multiplication with the second array transposed, so instead of normal `ij,jk->ik`, you transpose the second matrix by `ij,kj->ik`:

```
np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', a, b)

#array([[ 8, 24],
#       [14, 42]])
```

which is equivalent to:

```
np.dot(a, b.T)

#array([[ 8, 24],
#       [14, 42]])
```

---

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [3,4,5]])
b = np.array([[0,1,2], [1,1,7]])
```

Comment: Yeah this works! Any chance you can point me to where I can learn this "ijk" indexing for einsum? Preferably with examples? The manual https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html isn't much to work with.

Comment: You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum), or [this](http://ajcr.net/Basic-guide-to-einsum/) and some explanation about [einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) may help as well.