# Speed up iterative algorithm in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm implementing the forward recursion for Hidden Markov Model: the necessary steps (a-b) are shown here

[image]

Below is my implementation

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import random

def gmmdensity(obs, w, mu, sd):
    # compute probability density function of gaussian mixture 
    gauss_mixt = norm.pdf(obs, mu, sd)[:,None]*w
    return gauss_mixt

def alpha(obs, states, A, pi, w, mu, sigma):    
    dens = np.sum(gmmdensity(obs, w, mu, sigma), axis = 2)
    # scaling factor is used to renormalize probabilities in order to
    # avoid numerical underflow
    scaling_factor = np.ones(len(obs))
    alpha_matrix = np.zeros((len(states), len(obs)))
    
    # for t = 0
    alpha_matrix[:,0] = pi*dens[0]
    scaling_factor[0] = 1/np.sum(alpha_matrix[:,0], axis = 0)
    alpha_matrix[:,0] *= scaling_factor[0]
    
    # for t == 1:T
    for t in range(1, len(obs)):
        alpha_matrix[:,t] = np.matmul(alpha_matrix[:,t-1], A)*dens[t]
        scaling_factor[t] = 1/np.sum(alpha_matrix[:,t], axis = 0)
        alpha_matrix[:,t] *= scaling_factor[t]

    return alpha_matrix, scaling_factor
```

Let's generate some data to run the algorithm

```
obs = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0, 1, size = 500), 
                        np.random.normal(1.5, 1, size = 500))).reshape(-1,1)
N = 2 # number of hidden states
M = 3 # number of mixture components
states = list(range(N))
pi = np.array([0.5, 0.5]) # initial probabilities
A = np.array([[0.8, 0.2], [0.3, 0.7]]) # transition matrix
mu = np.array([np.min(obs), np.median(obs), np.max(obs)]) # means of mixture components
sigma = np.array([1, 1, 1]) # variances of mixture components
w = np.array([[0.2, 0.3, 0.5], [0.6, 0.2, 0.2]]) # weights of mixture components
```

Let's see how fast the algorithm is

```
%timeit alpha(obs, states, A, pi, w, mu, sigma)
13.6 ms ± 1.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Is there any possibility to make this code faster? I thought about using numba or cython, but it never fully worked in this case.

Comment: I see no recursive functions in your code.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg You're right, corrected.

Comment: should try to [avoid recursion](https://youtu.be/1podU0jN4aU), which fortunately you are not using.

Comment: also, switch `for` loop for vectorised methods (`numpy` arrays) if you can. this will be meaningfully faster. [make python 100 times faster](https://youtu.be/e1zRI46ZSUo).

Comment: @D.L I guess that's exactly my question in this case, but I know no simple answer.

Comment: @thesecond, the video in the link gives a very decent starting point. You can extend the idea to your case from this.

Comment: I don't think the for loop is an issue here. Its 1000 iterations should barely make a dent in a 13 ms call. That's also why I don't expect big gains from numba or cython here. If you want to go faster, start by finding the bottleneck. You may gain a bit here and there by changing precision or exploring allternatives to e.g. matmul, but no point in doing so without profiling.

Comment: @MatthiasHuschle It turns out Numba is pretty well suited for this use-case in the end ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Numba can strongly speed up this code, especially with basic loops. This answer comes lately compared to the others, but it provides the **fastest implementation** so far.

---

This is indeed typically a situation where Numba can strongly speed up the computation. Indeed, `np.matmul` takes more than 1 µs on my machine to multiply a vector of only 2 items with a matrix of 2x2. This should take clearly no more than 0.01 µs on my machine (assuming data are in the L1 cache). Most of the time is lost in the Numpy call overheads. `np.sum` takes > 3 µs while it should take about few nanoseconds (for the same reason) : it is just a sum of 2 numbers!

To solve this efficiently in Numba you need to use basic loops and avoid creating new temporary arrays (allocations are expensive in such a basic loop). Note that `gmmdensity` cannot be easily translated to Numba since it calls `norm.pdf` of Scipy which is AFAIK not supported by Numba yet. Here is a fast implementation:

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit('(int64, int64, float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1], float64[::1])')
def fast_iteration(obsLen, statesLen, dens, A, pi):
    # scaling factor is used to renormalize probabilities in order to
    # avoid numerical underflow
    scaling_factor = np.ones(obsLen)
    alpha_matrix = np.zeros((statesLen, obsLen))
    
    # for t = 0
    alpha_matrix[:,0] = pi*dens[0]
    scaling_factor[0] = 1/np.sum(alpha_matrix[:,0], axis = 0)
    alpha_matrix[:,0] *= scaling_factor[0]
    tmp = np.zeros(statesLen)

    for t in range(1, obsLen):
        # Line: alpha_matrix[:,t] = np.matmul(alpha_matrix[:,t-1], A)*dens[t]
        for i in range(statesLen):
            s = 0.0
            for k in range(statesLen):
                s += alpha_matrix[k, t-1] * A[k, i]
            tmp[i] = s * dens[t, i]

        # Line: scaling_factor[t] = 1/np.sum(alpha_matrix[:,t], axis = 0)
        s = 0.0
        for i in range(statesLen):
            s += tmp[i]
        scaling_factor[t] = 1.0 / s

        # Line: alpha_matrix[:,t] *= scaling_factor[t]
        for i in range(statesLen):
            alpha_matrix[i, t] = tmp[i] * scaling_factor[t]

    return alpha_matrix, scaling_factor

@nb.njit('(float64[:,::1], float64[::1], float64[::1])')
def fast_normal_pdf(obs, mu, sigma):
    n, m = obs.shape[0], mu.size
    assert obs.shape[1] == 1
    assert mu.size == sigma.size
    inv_sigma = 1.0 / sigma
    one_over_sqrt_2pi = 1 / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)
    result = np.empty((n, m))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            tmp = (obs[i, 0] - mu[j]) * inv_sigma[j]
            tmp = np.exp(-0.5 * tmp * tmp)
            result[i, j] = one_over_sqrt_2pi * inv_sigma[j] * tmp
    return result

@nb.njit('(float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1], float64[::1], float64[::1])')
def fast_gmmdensitysum(obs, w, mu, sigma):
    pdf = fast_normal_pdf(obs, mu, sigma)
    result = np.zeros((pdf.shape[0], w.shape[0]))
    for i in range(pdf.shape[0]):
        for k in range(w.shape[0]):
            s = 0.0
            for j in range(pdf.shape[1]):
                s += pdf[i, j] * w[k, j]
            result[i, k] = s
    return result

def fast_alpha(obs, states, A, pi, w, mu, sigma):    
    dens = fast_gmmdensitysum(obs, w, mu, sigma)
    return fast_iteration(len(obs), len(states), dens, A, pi)


# Usage

obs = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0, 1, size = 500), 
                        np.random.normal(1.5, 1, size = 500))).reshape(-1,1)
N = 2 # number of hidden states
M = 3 # number of mixture components
states = list(range(N))
pi = np.array([0.5, 0.5]) # initial probabilities
A = np.array([[0.8, 0.2], [0.3, 0.7]]) # transition matrix
mu = np.array([np.min(obs), np.median(obs), np.max(obs)]) # means of mixture components
sigma = np.array([1, 1, 1], dtype=np.float64) # variances of mixture components
w = np.array([[0.2, 0.3, 0.5], [0.6, 0.2, 0.2]]) # weights of mixture components
```

Note that the type of `sigma` has been explicitly provided so it is correct. `fast_normal_pdf` and `fast_normal_pdf` are optimized implementations inspired by the good answer of @NickODell.

---

### Benchmark

Here are performance results on my machine with a i5-9600KF CPU:

```
Initial code:        10417.4 µs      x1
Andrej Kesely:         974.6 µs     x11
Nick ODell:            335.1 µs     x31
This implementation:    53.9 µs    x193    <------
```

While this implementation is bigger than others, it is **clearly the fastest implementation by a large margin**. It is **193 times faster** than the initial implementation on my machine, and more than 6 times faster than the other fastest one so far.

`fast_gmmdensitysum` is the most expensive part (>60%), especially the `np.exp` function (~40%) which is hard to optimize further.

Comment: Nice fast implementation, +1. I'll look at this later, seems that the techniques used here will be useful later :)

Comment: I cannot express how thankful I am. I guess it took a bit of work to write that code, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

I profiled this code, and found the following ideas were helpful for speeding it up.

- Saving/loading the `alpha_matrix[:,t]` vector multiple times is slow. It is faster to keep the vector you are manipulating as a local variable until you are done manipulating it. Same for `scaling_factor[t]`.
- Accessing `alpha_matrix[:,t]` has poor memory locality. It accesses an element, skips a few elements, accesses an element, and so on. Since you are doing `alpha_matrix[:,t]` everywhere, I found it was easier to index if you swap the two indices. Once we're done manipulating it, we can transpose it back to its original state so you don't have to change the rest of your code.
- Running `np.sum(..., axis=0)` on an array with only one axis is the same thing as `np.sum()` without an axis argument, but using the axis argument is slower.
- Multiplying by the `w` array creates a big (1000, 2, 3) array, which you then sum the last dimension of. You can combine these two steps using `einsum()`. This is faster because it avoids creating the big intermediate array. I copied the code for this from [Using Python numpy einsum to obtain dot product between 2 Matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896939/using-python-numpy-einsum-to-obtain-dot-product-between-2-matrices).
- `scipy.stats.norm.pdf()` is weirdly slow here. I think SciPy is using a finite difference of the CDF to define the PDF? I re-coded it with the [formula for the normal PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), and found that was 3x faster.
- The main loop of the algorithm can be extracted into a new function, which we can use Numba to accelerate. (This provided the bulk of the speedup, but I prefer to do this kind of thing last because Numba functions can't be profiled.)

This adds up to a roughly 40x speedup on the provided benchmark:

```
%timeit alpha_orig(obs, states, A, pi, w, mu, sigma)
14.4 ms ± 159 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit alpha(obs, states, A, pi, w, mu, sigma)
308 µs ± 2.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Full code:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import random
import numba as nb


@nb.njit()
def fast_normal_pdf(x, mu, sigma):
    x = (x - mu) / sigma
    one_over_sqrt_2pi = 1 / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)
    return (1 / sigma) * one_over_sqrt_2pi * np.exp(-0.5*x*x)


def gmmdensitysum(obs, w, mu, sd):
    pdf = fast_normal_pdf(obs, mu, sigma)
    return np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', pdf, w)


@nb.njit()
def alpha_inner(N, alpha_matrix, dens, scaling_factor):
    for t in range(1, N):
        current_alpha = (alpha_matrix[t-1] @ A) * dens[t]
        current_scaling_factor = 1 / current_alpha.sum()
        current_alpha *= current_scaling_factor
        scaling_factor[t] = current_scaling_factor
        alpha_matrix[t] = current_alpha


def alpha(obs, states, A, pi, w, mu, sigma):
    dens = gmmdensitysum(obs, w, mu, sigma)
    # scaling factor is used to renormalize probabilities in order to
    # avoid numerical underflow
    scaling_factor = np.ones(len(obs))
    alpha_matrix = np.zeros((len(obs), len(states)))
    
    # for t = 0
    alpha_matrix[0] = pi * dens[0]
    scaling_factor[0] = 1 / np.sum(alpha_matrix[0])
    alpha_matrix[0] *= scaling_factor[0]

    alpha_inner(len(obs), alpha_matrix, dens, scaling_factor)

    return alpha_matrix.T, scaling_factor
```

Comment: With the rearrangements you've made this is additional ~3-4x faster than my numba version. (0.000423 vs 0.00013) +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) version of the function (NOTE: The numba version raises `NumbaPerformanceWarning: '@' is faster on contiguous arrays`, it probably needs the input matrices rearranged(?)):

```py
import random
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from scipy.stats import norm


def gmmdensity(obs, w, mu, sd):
    # compute probability density function of gaussian mixture
    gauss_mixt = norm.pdf(obs, mu, sd)[:, None] * w
    return gauss_mixt


def alpha(obs, states, A, pi, w, mu, sigma):
    dens = np.sum(gmmdensity(obs, w, mu, sigma), axis=2)
    # scaling factor is used to renormalize probabilities in order to
    # avoid numerical underflow
    scaling_factor = np.ones(len(obs))
    alpha_matrix = np.zeros((len(states), len(obs)))

    # for t = 0
    alpha_matrix[:, 0] = pi * dens[0]
    scaling_factor[0] = 1 / np.sum(alpha_matrix[:, 0], axis=0)
    alpha_matrix[:, 0] *= scaling_factor[0]

    # for t == 1:T
    for t in range(1, len(obs)):
        alpha_matrix[:, t] = np.matmul(alpha_matrix[:, t - 1], A) * dens[t]
        scaling_factor[t] = 1 / np.sum(alpha_matrix[:, t], axis=0)
        alpha_matrix[:, t] *= scaling_factor[t]

    return alpha_matrix, scaling_factor


@njit
def pdf_numba(x, loc, scale):
    x = (x - loc) / scale
    return (np.exp(-(x**2) / 2) / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) / scale


@njit
def gmmdensity_numba(obs, w, mu, sd):
    # compute probability density function of gaussian mixture
    gauss_mixt = pdf_numba(obs, mu, sd)[:, None] * w
    return gauss_mixt


@njit
def alpha_numba(obs, states, A, pi, w, mu, sigma):
    dens = np.sum(gmmdensity_numba(obs, w, mu, sigma), axis=2)
    # scaling factor is used to renormalize probabilities in order to
    # avoid numerical underflow

    scaling_factor = np.ones(len(obs))
    alpha_matrix = np.zeros((len(states), len(obs)))

    # for t = 0

    alpha_matrix[:, 0] = pi * dens[0]
    scaling_factor[0] = 1 / np.sum(alpha_matrix[:, 0], axis=0)
    alpha_matrix[:, 0] *= scaling_factor[0]

    # for t == 1:T
    for t in range(1, len(obs)):
        # NumbaPerformanceWarning: '@' is faster on contiguous arrays
        # probably needs alpha_matrix rearranged(?)
        x = alpha_matrix[:, t - 1] @ A

        alpha_matrix[:, t] = x * dens[t]
        scaling_factor[t] = 1 / np.sum(alpha_matrix[:, t], axis=0)
        alpha_matrix[:, t] *= scaling_factor[t]

    return alpha_matrix, scaling_factor


np.random.seed(41)
obs = np.concatenate(
    (np.random.normal(0, 1, size=500), np.random.normal(1.5, 1, size=500))
).reshape(-1, 1)
N = 2  # number of hidden states
M = 3  # number of mixture components
states = np.arange(N)
pi = np.array([0.5, 0.5])  # initial probabilities
A = np.array([[0.8, 0.2], [0.3, 0.7]])  # transition matrix
mu = np.array([np.min(obs), np.median(obs), np.max(obs)])  # means of mixture components
sigma = np.array([1, 1, 1])  # variances of mixture components
w = np.array([[0.2, 0.3, 0.5], [0.6, 0.2, 0.2]])  # weights of mixture components

a_1, s_1 = alpha(obs, states, A, pi, w, mu, sigma)
a_2, s_2 = alpha_numba(obs, states, A, pi, w, mu, sigma)

assert np.allclose(a_1, a_2)
assert np.allclose(s_1, s_2)

t1 = timeit("alpha(obs, states, A, pi, w, mu, sigma)", number=100, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit(
    "alpha_numba(obs, states, A, pi, w, mu, sigma)", number=100, globals=globals()
)
print(t1 / 100)
print(t2 / 100)
```

Prints on my machine (AMD 5700x):

```
0.005626231823116541
0.0003328173188492656
```

Which is ~17x speedup.