# Cosine similarity between matching rows in numpy ndarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, distance, cosine-similarity

I have 2 ndarrays of `(n_samples, n_dimensions)` and I want for each pair of corresponding rows, so the output would be `(n_samples, )`

Using [`sklearn's implementation`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html) I get `(n_samples, n_samples)` result - which obviously makes a lot of irrelevant calculations which is unacceptable in my case.

Using [`1 - scipy's implementation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html) is impossible because it expects vectors and not matrices.

What would be the most efficient way to execute what I'm looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for the similarity between each `x[n, :]` and `y[n, :]` - this should give me `n` results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the two arrays `x` and `y` have the same shape,

1. Compute the element-wise dot product using `np.einsum` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15622926/4909087))
2. Compute the product of the L2 (euclidean) norm for each row of `x` and `y`
3. Divide the result from (1) by (2)

```
def matrix_cosine(x, y):
    return np.einsum('ij,ij->i', x, y) / (
              np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1) * np.linalg.norm(y, axis=1)
    )
```

And a little code to test;

```
x = np.random.randn(100000, 100)

%timeit matrix_cosine(x, x)
82.8 ms ± 2.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

assert np.allclose(matrix_cosine(x, x), np.ones(x.shape[0]))
```

Comment: This is perfect, I'm still surprised this is not trivial in any of the libraries

Comment: @bluesummers This code is licensed under the "do whatever the hell you want with it" license, feel free to issue a PR to the devs on git with it. Cheers :)