# Vectorize angle calculation of all combinations from matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, optimization, vectorization

*See edits below*

I have a rather big matrix `x` (3xn, n >> 1000) with limited information about the relation of each column.
From this matrix `x`, I need to find the biggest angle and the corresponding indices of two columns.
Currently I'm using two `for`-loops, which takes way to long, see code below.

I know that I can vectorize the norm of the vector, e.g. via `np.linalg.norm(x, axis=0)`.
Also, I found some info on how to vectorize the dot product [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616742/vectorized-way-of-calculating-row-wise-dot-product-two-matrices-with-scipy).
However, this will only calculate the dot product between each column, not between say columns 1 and 3.

Is there a way to optimize or even vectorize the problem?

```py
import numpy as np

# Calculate the max angle between two vectors
len_x = 1000
x = np.random.rand(3,len_x) # 3xn matrix

ang_max = 0 # maximum angle
n_max   = 0 # n-index of maximum angle
m_max   = 0 # m-index of maximum angle

for n in range(len_x - 1):
     vn = np.array([x[0][n], \
                    x[1][n], \
                    x[2][n]])
     for m in range(n + 1, len_x):
         vm = np.array([x[0][m], \
                        x[1][m], \
                        x[2][m]])

         ang = np.arccos(np.dot(vn,vm)/(np.linalg.norm(vn)*np.linalg.norm(vm)))

         if ang > ang_max:
             ang_max = ang
             n_max = n
             m_max = m
```

**Edit:**

Using `np.einsum` I was able to vectorize the inner loop away.
This improved the execution time by a factor of 44, at least in my test case (from 31.98 s down to 0.725 s).
This is a significant improvement, yet I feel that vectorizing the outer loop might give another speed-up by a similar factor.
Thus, I won't mark the question as answered, as log as the outer loop is not vectorized as well.

```py
import numpy as np

# Calculate the max angle between two vectors
len_x = 1000
x = np.random.rand(3,len_x) # 3xn matrix

ang_max = 0 # maximum angle
n_max   = 0 # n-index of maximum angle
m_max   = 0 # m-index of maximum angle

vm      = np.array(x)
vm_norm = np.linalg.norm(vm, axis=0)

for n in range(len_x - 1):
    vn = np.array([float(x[n]) - xs, \
                   float(y[n]) - ys, \
                   float(z[n]) - zs])
    ang = np.arccos(np.divide(np.einsum('ij,ij->j', vn[:,None], vm[:,:,0]),(np.linalg.norm(vn)*vm_norm)[:,0]))
    maxang = max(ang)

    if maxang > ang_max:
        ang_max = maxang
        n_max = n
        m_max = np.where(ang == maxang)[0][0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, what I was looking for is actually called [[Gramian Matrix]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix), a matrix whose elements are all possible combinations of inner products. In my case, that translate to the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

# Calculate the max angle between two vectors
len_x = 1000
x = np.random.rand(3,len_x) # 3xn matrix

ang_max = 0 # maximum angle
n_max   = 0 # n-index of maximum angle
m_max   = 0 # m-index of maximum angle

vm      = np.array(x)
vm_norm = np.linalg.norm(vm, axis=0)

ang = np.arccos(np.divide(vm.T.dot(vm), (vm_norm.dot(vm_norm))))

ang_max = np.amax(ang)
argw    = np.argwhere(ang == np.amax(ang))
n_max   = argw[0, 0]
m_max   = argw[0, 1]
```

The code gives me another performance improvement of roughly 4 times, bringing the execution time down to ~0.2 s.

Now, as the inner product is symmetric, half of the calculations of `vm.dot(vm)` are redundant. I'm not sure how to further optimize for this edge case without adding too much complexity. However, I have a strong feeling, that `numpy` is somehow smart enough to detect the redundance and auto-optimize it.