# What is the most efficient way to call a function on a 2D ndarray of coordinates?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a ndarray of size (M, N, 3). It holds M x N points, each of which is identified by its x, y, and z coordinates. I also have a function 'foo'. 'foo' takes in a point as a ndarray of size (, 3). Is there a faster way to call 'foo' on each of the M x N points in my array than to use two nested for loops?

So far, this is what I have tried. My array is the variable 'sample_array'.

```
num_rows = sample_array.shape[0]
num_columns = sample_array.shape[1]
solution = np.zeros((num_rows, num_columns))

for row in range(num_rows):
   for column in range(num_columns):
      point = sample_array[row, column]
      solution[row, column] = foo(point)
```

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array), which describes using these two solutions:

```
np.vectorize(foo)
np.array(map(foo, sample_array))
```

However, I am not sure how to specify that I don't want the function mapped to every one of the M x N x 3 floats. Instead, I would like it to map the function to be called on each of the M x N (, 3) ndarrays.

Thank you!

Comment: For general function `foo`, the simple answer is **No**. Both `map` and `np.vectorize` are just fancy ways to write a for loop, just like you did.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to use map, np.vectorize, or some other function to at least reduce the number of lines of code required?

Comment: As long the function only accepts 1 point, there isn't much you can do about speed.  It has to be called `N*M` times; that's the main time consumer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `np.apply_along_axis(function, axis=2, arr=your_input_array)` which will slice the array along the 3rd axis and apply the **function** to each slice, i.e. point.

Find the doc here [np.apply_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

Comment: In my expience this `apply` is convenient, but not faster.

Answer (score 0):

A way to use `map` is:

```
solution = np.array(list(map(foo, sample_array.reshape(-1,3)) ))\
             .reshape(sample_array.shape[:2])
```

Comment: @hpaulj it doesn't. updated with `list` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the function `foo` you're calling will accept arrays as input. In general, it's good style for any function to accept all arrays as long as the *first* dimension is as expected. For example, the function

```py
import numpy


def length(x):
    return numpy.sqrt(x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2 + x[2] ** 2)
```

computes the length of a vector, but also accepts arrays of shape `(3, ...)` (it doesn't even matter how many dimensions follow) and does the right thing.

This design has the following advantages:

- The code works for scalars and arrays.
- It works for arrays of arbitrary dimensionality.
- [Working in the first dimension is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39657770/353337) (with C-contiguous ordering).
- It often leads to clean code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So this would require that the input be of shape (3, M, N), correct? Is there a way to achieve this, using your method, that can in the shape (M, N, 3)? Would it be bad practice to store my points in this way?

Comment: It's very common to store arrays as `(n, 3)`, mostly attributed to the fact that `print()`ing looks nicer. It's actually computationally more efficient to keep the leading dimension small. You can of course always use `moveaxis`, but this actually moves around memory and takes time. I'd organize my code such that the shape of the array is `(3, ...)` right from the start.

Answer (score 0):

In fewer lines of code:

```
solution = np.vectorize(foo)(*sample_array.reshape(-1, 3).T)
```