# Vectorize Forward Propagation

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, vectorization

I have made a neural network from scratch and want to make it run a little bit faster. I'm wondering if vectorizing my forward prop would make it faster.
My current forward prop code is:

```
def forwardProp(self, inputs):
    for i in range (self.dimensions[1]):
        self.secondLayerNeurons[i] = self.relu(np.dot(self.firstLayerWeights[i], inputs)+self.firstLayerBiases[i])
    for i in range (self.dimensions[2]):
        self.outputNeurons[i] = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.secondLayerWeights[i], self.secondLayerNeurons)+self.secondLayerBiases[i])
```

If vectorization will make this faster, how would I vectorize this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm wondering if vectorizing my forward prop would make it faster**

Yes!

**How would I vectorize this?**

You want to eliminate loops and figure out vector algebra that will do the same thing.

Let's say `self.firstLayerWeights.shape` is `(N, D)`. You want to [calculate the row-wise dot product of this matrix with `inputs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616742/vectorized-way-of-calculating-row-wise-dot-product-two-matrices-with-scipy). Let's say you implement this logic in a function called `rowwise_dot`

```
def rowwise_dot(inpA, inpB):
    # Calculate and return rowwise dot
```

Now you have the `rowwise_dot` function, you can add the entire vector of `self.firstLayerBiases` without having to loop,

```
rowwise_dot(self.firstLayerWeights, inputs) + self.firstLayerBiases
```

Next, make sure `self.relu` and `self.sigmoid` can take vectors and return whatever you need them to for each element of the vector. This might involve similar shenanigans as vectorizing the rowwise dot product.

So in the end you have:

```
def forwardProp(self, inputs):
    self.secondLayerNeurons = self.relu(rowwise_dot(self.firstLayerWeights, inputs) + self.firstLayerBiases)
    self.outputNeurons = self.sigmoid(rowwise_dot(self.secondLayerWeights, self.secondLayerNeurons) + self.secondLayerBiases)
```

Comment: Current Sigmoid:  return 1/(1+np.exp(-x)) where x is a double, how would I vectorize that?

Comment: It's already vectorized. `1/(1 + np.exp(-x))` already gives you the element-wise sigmoid function of the vector `x`

Comment: Would there be any numpy functions that function like the rowwise function?

Comment: Many numpy functions have an `axis` argument that perform the operation along the specified axis.

Comment: Thanks, how would I make relu so that it can take in an array without using a loop? The code is currently return max(0.0, x)

Comment: For `relu`, `max(0, x)` will not work because you want `x_return[i] = max(0, x[i])`.

Comment: `x_return = x[:]; x_return[x < 0] = 0; return x_return;` should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try it.

Answer (score -1):

Vectorizing forward prop makes the MLP run a lot faster. I used the @ operator.

```
    def forwardProp(self, inputs):
        self.secondLayerNeurons = self.sigmoid(self.w1 @ inputs + self.b1)
        self.outputNeurons = self.sigmoid(self.w2 @ self.secondLayerNeurons + self.b2)
```